# C++ Multi-Client TCP Server

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I want to make a server and client program with TCP protocol using C++. The server must be able to handle multiple client at once. But the problem is for example, after starting the server, I run 2 clients with the server 's IP address and port as parameters. Next, both clients are sending data to server. At first, both clients could send data to server and the server was able read the data. But, once the server has received data from the second client, it seems that it stopped receiving from the first client. Do you have any solution?

Here is the server code

```
using namespace std;

void *task1(void *);

static int connFd;
void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int pId, portNo, listenFd;
    socklen_t len; //store size of the address
    bool loop = false;
struct sockaddr_in svrAdd, clntAdd;

pthread_t threadA[3];

if (argc < 2)
{
    cerr << "Syntam : ./server <port>" << endl;
    return 0;
}

portNo = atoi(argv[1]);

if((portNo > 65535) || (portNo < 2000))
{
    cerr << "Please enter a port number between 2000 - 65535" << endl;
    return 0;
}

//create socket
listenFd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

if(listenFd < 0)
{
    cerr << "Cannot open socket" << endl;
    return 0;
}

bzero((char*) &svrAdd, sizeof(svrAdd));

svrAdd.sin_family = AF_INET;
svrAdd.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
svrAdd.sin_port = htons(portNo);

//bind socket
if(bind(listenFd, (struct sockaddr *)&svrAdd, sizeof(svrAdd)) < 0)
{
    cerr << "Cannot bind" << endl;
    return 0;
}

    listen(listenFd, 5);

    int noThread = 0;

    while (noThread < 3)
    {
        socklen_t len = sizeof(clntAdd);
        cout << "Listening" << endl;

    //this is where client connects. svr will hang in this mode until           client conn
        connFd = accept(listenFd, (struct sockaddr *)&clntAdd, &len);

        if (connFd < 0)
        {
            cerr << "Cannot accept connection" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else   
        {
            cout << "Connection successful" << endl;
        }

        pthread_create(&threadA[noThread], NULL, task1, NULL); 

        noThread++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threadA[i], NULL);
    }  
}

void *task1 (void *dummyPt)
{
    cout << "Thread No: " << pthread_self() << endl;
    char test[256];
    bzero(test, 256);
    bool loop = false;
    while(!loop)
    {       
        bzero(test, 256);     
        int n = read(connFd, test, 255);
        if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
        printf("Here is the message: %s\n",test);            
    }
    cout << "\nClosing thread and conn" << endl;
    close(connFd);
}
```

And the client code

```
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int listenFd, portNo;
    bool loop = false;
    struct sockaddr_in svrAdd;
    struct hostent *server;

    if(argc < 3)
    {
        cerr<<"Syntax : ./client <host name> <port>"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    portNo = atoi(argv[2]);

    if((portNo > 65535) || (portNo < 2000))
    {
        cerr<<"Please enter port number between 2000 - 65535"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }       

    //create client skt
    listenFd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if(listenFd < 0)
    {   
        cerr << "Cannot open socket" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

    if(server == NULL)
    {
        cerr << "Host does not exist" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    bzero((char *) &svrAdd, sizeof(svrAdd));
    svrAdd.sin_family = AF_INET;

    bcopy((char *) server -> h_addr, (char *) &svrAdd.sin_addr.s_addr, server -> h_length);

    svrAdd.sin_port = htons(portNo);

    int checker = connect(listenFd,(struct sockaddr *) &svrAdd, sizeof(svrAdd));

    if (checker < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot connect!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    //send stuff to server
    for(;;)
    {
        char s[300];
        //cin.clear();
        //cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        cout << "Enter stuff: ";
        bzero(s, 300);
        cin.getline(s, 300);

        write(listenFd, s, strlen(s));
    }
}
```

Comment: You got an answer to your original question. Attempting to implement that answer caused you to get new errors. You should not deface your post by adding the errors, which make no sense in the context of the original question which is still in the post. Instead, post a new question for the errors. I've edited the question back to how it was to preserve the integrity of the answer

Answer (score 4):

Yor `connFd` is a global variable, which you access from your main thread and all handling threads. This will not do! Imagine that - you've accepted the first connection and set the variable to the receiving socket. You've spawn the handling thread, which started reading. Next thing you know, another connection is coming along and you are receiving it as well! This very moment `connFd` points to the new connection, so the thread which is already using it will suddenly switch to the new connection! Of course it is not good.

The way to fix this problem is to pass the connection to the thread in such a way that is is not shared across threads. And easiest way of doing so is to use C++ thread class.

For example, this is code fragment illustrating the above idea:

```
void handle_connection(int fd) {
   ... <your task1 code>
}

... 
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
...
int conn = accept(listenFd, (struct sockaddr *)&clntAdd, &len);
threads.push_back(std::thread(&handle_connection, conn));
...

... (in the end)
for (auto&& t : threads)
    t.join();
```

Comment: After implementing your suggestion, I got some errors. Please look at my update.